# save image from URL to wordpress media library

Tags: php, wordpress

I have got a function which saves as stores the image from a url, the only problem is it all seems to work fine other than the image "can't be found"

The image and the name are in the media library but the image is broken as when you open image via url it says "not found"

Can you let me know if I have missed something.

```
function set_image_from_url($url) {


    $tmp = download_url( $url );

    $file_array = array(
        'name' => basename( $url ),
        'tmp_name' => $tmp
    );

    /**
     * Check for download errors
     * if there are error unlink the temp file name
     */
    if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
        @unlink( $file_array[ 'tmp_name' ] );
        return $tmp;
    }

    /**
     * now we can actually use media_handle_sideload
     * we pass it the file array of the file to handle
     * and the post id of the post to attach it to
     * $post_id can be set to '0' to not attach it to any particular post
     */
    $post_id = '0';

    $id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_id );

    /**
     * We don't want to pass something to $id
     * if there were upload errors.
     * So this checks for errors
     */
    if ( is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
        @unlink( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
        return $id;
    }

    /**
     * No we can get the url of the sideloaded file
     * $value now contains the file url in WordPress
     * $id is the attachment id
     */
    $value = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );

// Now you can do something with $value (or $id)

    return $id;

}
```

Comment: If you're really sure that the path to the image is correct when requesting it with an url, do you have a `.htaccess` file? If yes, please post its content in the question.

Comment: use media_sideload_image wordpress function

Comment: @onlinewebsite what is the difference between that and the media_handle_sideload function I have used?

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.2/src/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L862

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a really silly answer but...

I changed the default URL in local as I wanted to have it show images from the live site. Setting it back to the local uploads folder location started to show the images correctly.

Posted the answer incase someone else comes up with the same issue. Check your settings > media > Full URL path to files.

Thanks all!